# map paste (p) to "0p

Tags: vim, vi

In .vimrc I tried to do

```
nmap p "0p
```

But with this row my vim just hangs. Can anyone help me? What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying this because when I yank a line and if I use del button after yanking, then the register "" changes to the character I deleted. But register "0 stays the same.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you hit an infinite loop: you're binding a key to a command *that includes itself*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Vim attempts to recursively map `p`, resulting in an infinite loop. Use [`nnoremap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:nnoremap) instead:

```
nnoremap p "0p
```

Comment: This works fine, but you lose cut operation. I prefer to use nnoremap d "_d, so this way x can be used for cut operations.